# Get top level class name when inheritance and class alias is used

Tags: php, oop, class

I have some classes extended this way:

```
class Baseresidence extends CActiveRecord {
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className); // framework needs, can't modify
    }    
}

class Site1Residence extends Baseresidence {

}
```

and finally

```
class_alias('Site1Residence', 'Residence'); // this is part of an autoloader
```

So in the end I have like this `Residence extends Site1Residence extends Baseresidence extends CActiveRecord`

In the Baseresidence I have a static method `model()` which retrieves an instance.

Now I can call::

```
$r=Residence::model();
```

The problem is that `__CLASS__` constant is used as default value, and that on that level is Baseresidence, and I need there the top level class name (created with the alias) and it should be 'Residence'

if I do:

```
echo get_class($r); // the Baseresidence is printed
```

The goal is to print `residence`

I do not want to pass anything when calling `$r=Residence::model();` I would like to resolve it on the roots.

How to get the top level class name on that level?

Comment: Constant `__CLASS__`, used in class `Baseresidence` will always contain `Baseresidence`. You can't change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
get_called_class();
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php

From the docs:

```
class foo {
    static public function test() {
        var_dump(get_called_class());
    }
}

class bar extends foo {
}

foo::test();
bar::test();
```

The above example will output:

```
string(3) "foo"
string(3) "bar"
```

Comment: Correct answer, but I noticed one comment: `// framework needs, can't modify` - if he can't modify that line... I'm not sure he will be able to use this solution.

Comment: I can change `$className` variable before. This is a good solution and there is a solution for `get_called_class` for PHP 5.2.4 too. http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php

Comment: @OZ_, The way I read that line, is that the framework needs the class name. Passing the top level class name should have no negitive effect.

Comment: @Pentium10, look in the comments of that doc page, there are alternatives to that function for PHP 5.2

Comment: @Pentium10 you mean `debug_backtrace`? I'm not sure it's best idea in point of performance. It's better to upgrade to 5.3.

Comment: Also, you can use `static::class` instead

Comment: This is not the right answer.  The question specifically asked about using `class_alias` and this answer does not address this.