# Getting the alias name from inside the class

Tags: php, oop

Lets say i have a class Foo with a method printname(),
Then i create an alias Bar to the Foo and make the call: Bar::printname(),
I want this call to print "Bar" on the screen.

```
<?php

class Foo {

    function printname () {
        ...
    }
}

class_alias('Foo', 'Bar');

Bar::printname(); // Print "Bar"
```

In short, i want the class Foo to have a function that prints the name of the alias it's called with, and not the name of the class(Foo).

Thanks :)

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229605/in-php-how-do-you-get-the-called-aliased-class-when-using-class-alias) might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, but I always thought class aliases were a silly idea anyway.

If you really need to alias a class, you could cheat and use inheritance.

```
class Foo {

    public static function printname() {
        echo get_called_class();
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo { }

Bar::printname(); // Print "Bar"
```